# Laravel add a class file from parent folder

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a Laravel project as the subfolder of another project. The main project is developed in core PHP. Now I want to access a class in the main project inside my Laravel project. I know if it is inside the Laravel project I can use autoload in composer.json. But here it is outside the Laravel folder. The folder structure is

Main Project/
  Classes/
    MyClass.php
  Laravel/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    database/

Please help.

Comment: does the file you are wishing to access have laravel dependencies? can you achieve what you want with an api?

Comment: @Alex          No. I just want to access some variables from it.

Comment: have you tried a relative path in autoload like "Classes\\" : "../Classes/"

Comment: then you should provide an example of what you wish to accomplish, what does this class look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work

```
public function example(Request $request)
{
    $_app_path   = app_path();
    $_r_app_path = str_replace('\Laravel\app','',$_app_path);
    include($_r_app_path . '\Classes\MyClass.php');
    $_obj = new \MyClass('arg1','arg2');
    $_obj->hello_world();
}
```

if we assume that MyClass.php is

```
<?php


class MyClass
{
    private $arg1 = null;
    private $arg2 = null;

    public function __construct($arg1,$arg2)
    {
        $this->arg1 = $arg1;
        $this->arg2 = $arg2;
    }


    public function hello_world()
    {
        echo "Hello from outside ".$this->arg1." ".$this->arg2;
    }
}
```